# How can I show a interactive map?

Tags: wms, wfs, web-service

I am trying to develop a web app like [this](http://www.mapas.fcs.uner.edu.ar/mapas/). That is, I want to show a map with points and when the users clicks on a point, it should display some information about it.
Can I do that with TinyOWS?

This app requires WMS, WFS or both services?

Comment: It is using Openlayers which supports WMS & WFS http://openlayers.org/

Comment: Sorry I forgot... Yes, I'm using OpenLayers but I don't know if TinyOWS supports that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an openlayers stylemap and the "selected" render intent.

Your TinyOWS will need to provide the information in a variable called (say) "feature_attribute_variable"

```
var style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({

            'default' : new OpenLayers.Style({
                   ..style for when not clicked..
            }),
            'select' : new OpenLayers.Style({
                  ..style for when clicked..
                   'label': '${feature_attribute_variable}',
            })
});
```

Create the layer and add this stylemap to it and the label will show when selected.

Alternatively you could extend the Openlayers select control to create and show a popup.

You can use a WFS layer as follows:-

```
 var strategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()];
 var olLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('WFS', {

                        strategies: strategies,
                        styleMap: style,
                        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                            version: "1.1.0",
                            srsName: YOURprojection,
                            url: YOURwfsurl,
                            etc...

                        })
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try but how can I should create the layer with OpenLayers in this case using OpenLayers.Layer.WMS or OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS?

Comment: See edit. I'd use a WFS service